# Area under curve in MatLab

Tags: matlab, statistics

can anyone tell me how to determine the AUC of the signal shown in the screenshot in Matlab? I would like to determine the AUC above the blue line (demarcation) over the 120 sec. period. Can anyone tell me how to do this in Matlab? Many thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: I am reluctant to click on arbitrary links. To answer your question in general, area under curve is found by integrating the function. How you integrate depends on whether you have a function definition, or sample data points, or just an image to work with. Which of these do you have?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few functions in Matlab to integrate or approximate an integral of a function. Depending on the size of your vector - therefore depending on the sampling rate of that signal - some functions can save you time.

1. Remove the area under the blue line. So, I assume the y-axis value for the horizontal blue line is positive (x>0). Just subtract the blue line from your original signal and set all negative values to 0.

If `y` is your signal, `x` is the cutoff for the blue line (a single number) and it is positive:

```
y2 = y-x; % subtract blue line
y2(y2<0) = 0; % set negative values to 0
```

2. Integrate the resulting `y2` curve. You can approximate the integral of the signal with the [Trapezoidal numerical integration method from matlab](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) -- `trapz` function:

But you need to know the sampling rate of the original signal to select the length for the specific 120 seconds.

```
freq = ?; % Sampling rate in Hz
% For 120 seconds:
sampling _length = 120 * freq;
% select the points for the first 120 seconds and approximate the integral
Q = trapz(y2([1:sampling _length]))
```

If you want to deepen in this topic:
https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/integration-of-numeric-data.html

Comment: Thanks Roberto, appreciate your help a lot. Thank you for the detailed guidance! Great!